# PHP - how do I check if today's date matches date stored in database?

Tags: php, mysql

PHP.  I'm trying to compare two dates. One is dateofbirth stored in a MySQL table and the other is today's date without the year.  if the date (m-d) stored in database matches today's date (m-d) a window will pop up.

This is for a Linux server, running MySQL 5, PHP 5.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM perfil_aluno WHERE id_usuarios = 
'".$_SESSION['usuarioId']."' ";
$query1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql1);
$dados1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);

$dob = date('m-d', strtotime($dados1['dateofbirth']));
$2day = date('m-d');

if($dob == $2day) {
// execute some code...
}
```

If the month and day of birth (m-d) stored in the database matches today's date month and day, a window will pop up wishing the user a Happy Birthday.

Comment: "MySQL 5, PHP 5" Why? Those are both quite old, PHP 5 is end-of-life, as is PHP 7.0 and 7.1.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects to compare the dates like so:

```php
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m-d', $dob);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m-d', $2day);

if ($date1 == $date2) {
    // execute some code...
}
```

The `!` prevents taking the current timestamp instead of 00:00:00 so it would be safer to use it in a comparision without the time part needed. See in the comments [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#118358)